# increase the TextLabel size when using UITableViewCellStyleValue2

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

I would like to use `UITableViewCellStyleValue2` but I would like to prevent creating a custom cell. However, I would like to increase the size of the `textLabel` size.
When I input the text for the `textLabel`s, it sometimes is too short. The `sizeToFit` doesn't either work here.

The result after I input my text:
[image]

I have also tried to log the current size but don't get any useful details:
I did:

```
NSLog(@"Label frame: %f %f %f %f", cell.textLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.textLabel.frame.origin.y, cell.textLabel.frame.size.width, cell.textLabel.frame.size.height);
```

And got:

> 2011-10-24 10:33:51.084 checkout[68350:fb03] Label frame: 0.000000
>   0.000000 0.000000 0.000000

I also tried overwriting the size, but that didn't work:

```
[cell.textLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 14.0f, 205.0f, 15.0f)];
```

How can I increase the size?

Comment: By the way, your log line can be written more simply as: NSLog(@"Label frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cell.textLabel.frame));

Comment: Thank you Benjie, I know. I just wanted to make sure the content was clear.

Comment: One question Paul: why you don't want to create a CustomTableViewCell?

Comment: @JackyBoy because I am building an library and I want to keep the "custom" code to a minimum. Best to use OS designed code cause that I don't have to adapt to iPhone/iPad/Future models.

Comment: Paul I don't think that's a valid argument. Every project have his needs... Limiting your options because you want to stick with what apple offers its not the best solution to be honest...

Comment: Ok, your opinion is noted and I'll keep it under consideration. Meanwhile, I would still like an answer on the question. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `UILabel *textLabel` in a `UITableViewCell` is heavily managed.

The simplest way to get around this issue is to add a label of your own to the cell (which you needn't have a subclass to do). You can use a `tag` to access the label later in order to modify it's text at a later point, and your label will still exist if/when you `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` assuming that you create it with said identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are using ios 5 SDK that customization is easy, just edit it in storyboard.
If that's not in ios 5, I think that can't be customized.

Comment: I use iOS5, but not story boards. Any other solutions? If Story board can do it without any custom classes, one can do it programatically.